# how to detect if an array isnt empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to detect if an array isn't empty in order to be able to do a certain call.
I tried using `if (![array ==nil])` however that doesn't compile.
I'm sure there is a really easy explanation to this.

#### Update

If array is empty I want to do this:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

If it has an object I want to do this:

```
array = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Did you declare it with `NSMutableArray array;`? Did you already assign it to anything else before this?

Comment: yes i declared it and i just started nsuserdefaults before this

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but the syntax for checking if the array is not `nil` would be `if (array != nil)` — no message-sending brackets. However, `nil` and an empty array are two different values. If you want to check for an empty array, use `if ([array count] != 0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declared it but did not assign anything to it at all:

```
NSMutableArray *array;
```

Then the array will be `nil`, meaning it isn't there at all so you can't say if it's empty or not, so you can't check anything.

If you *did* assign something to it, and you want to find out if the existing array is empty or not, that would depend on how you created it first.

- If the array was assigned from some convenience method, it's autoreleased, so just do this:

  ```
  if ([array count] == 0) {
      array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  } else {
      array = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];
  }
  ```
- If the array was assigned from an init or copy method, or it was retained previously, store the count in a temporary variable, release the array and use the temporary variable to decide what to do:

  ```
  NSInteger count = [array count];
  [array release];

  if (count == 0) {
      array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  } else {
      array = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];
  }
  ```

Comment: im trying to do this alloc and init and array and if an array is empty and if its not empty to copy it using nsuserdefaults ([[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];) however i cant get it to work i tried the count but i cant implement it with the array creation

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd always use without differentation

```
array = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];
```

and set the default value in the user defaults to an empty array right away at program start before accessing the defaults (from Apple's example):

```
+ (void)initialize{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary
        dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray array] forKey:@"MyFavorites"];

    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
}
```

See [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000719-BAJFBAAH) on this.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are talking about NSArray, if `myArray` has not been properly alloced+initialized (what you are trying to check) its reference will be `nil`, so you can do:

```
if(myArray) //or even if(myArray != nil) since myArray will be a pointer
{
//properly inizialized
}
else
{
//not properly inited
}
```

If it's been inited on the other hand, you can test its emptiness by checking the `count` property which returns the number of elements it contains

```
if([myArray > 0]) 
//there is at least one element
}
else
{
//no elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use count function of NSArray. it will work on NSMutableArray too....

syntext will be,

int ct=[array count];

ct will have number of items in array.

if it us empty it will be Zero